# Como declara data no Node Express?

Tags: node.js

Estou com a seguinte entidade;

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ReviewsSchema = Schema({

    name: String,
    date: String,
    rating: String,
    comments: String,
    restaurantId: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Reviews', ReviewsSchema);
```

O que preciso é saber se estou declarando certo o atributo date, se não está certo como devo declara o atributo date?

Eu estou usando Node Express com MongoDB.

OBS: na aplicação Front-End vou precisar usar pipe para converter a data, é por isso que estou perguntando, porque eu acho que declarar date como String não está certo.

Comment: Existe um tipo de dados "date" no Mongoose.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma olhada na [documentação do Moongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html). Em JavaScript existe o tipo `Date`. Logo, você poderia construir o esquema como:

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ReviewsSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    date: Date,
    rating: String,
    comments: String,
    restaurantId: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Reviews', ReviewsSchema);
```